# Printing dictionary pair and next iteration's pair on one line in columns

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, iteration, key-value

I have a long list of 100+ unique (names don't repeat) key/value pairs which I'd like to print consolidated into two equal width columns.

- How do I get the next iteration's key/value? (i.e. How do I print two key/value pairs in the same iteration?)
- How do I get the pairs to print in two columns of 40 character width or the
  max width of the longest length of a pair?

Current loop:

```python
for key in example:
    print(f'{key}: {example[key]}')
```

Example dictionary:

```python
example = {
    'key0': 'val0',
    'key1': 'val1',
    'key2': 'val2',
    'key3': 'val3',
    'key4': 'val4',
    'key5': 'val5'
}
```

Desired result:

```
key0: val0            key1: val1
key2: val2            key3: val3
key4: val4            key5: val5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can run over the list of keys two by two

```
keys = list(example.keys())
for i in range(0,len(keys),2):
    key1 = keys[i]
    key2 = keys[i+1]
    print("%s:%s       %s:%s"%(key1,example[key1],key2,example[key2]))
```

output:

```
key0:val0       key1:val1
key2:val2       key3:val3
key4:val4       key5:val5
```

Answer (score 1):

Please don't ask two different questions. I'll just answer how to loop over the dictionary the way you want. There are plenty of other questions that explain how to format into fixed-width fields.

Use [`itertools.islice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to slice the odd and even elements of the dictionary, then use `zip()` to pair them up.

```
from itertools import islice, zip_longest

for (key1, value1), (key2, value2) in \
        zip_longest(islice(example.items(), 0, None, 2), 
                    islice(example.items(), 1, None, 2), 
                    fillvalue = (None, None)):
    if key2 is not None:
        print(f'{key1}: {value1}  {key2: value2}')
    else:
        print(f'{key1}: {value1}')
```

Comment: You can avoid `islice` (and reduce overhead somewhat by only iterating the input `dict` once, with no wrapping) at the expense of perhaps overly magic code by replacing both `islice`s passed to `zip_longest` with just `*[iter(example.items())]*2` (which passes the *same* iterator as the first and second positional argument, so it's pulled from twice on each iteration).

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```py
example = {
    "key0": "val0",
    "key1": "val1",
    "key2": "val2",
    "key3": "val3",
    "key4": "val4",
    "key5": "val5",
}

max_width = max([len(f"{k}: {v}") for k, v in example.items()])
column_width = max(40, max_width)

keys = list(example.keys())
values = list(example.values())

for i in range(0, len(keys) - 1, 2):
    left_key = keys[i]
    right_key = keys[i + 1]
    left_value = values[i]
    right_value = values[i + 1]
    n_spaces = column_width - len(f"{left_key}: {left_value}")

    print(f"{left_key}: {left_value}" + " " * n_spaces + f"{right_key}: {right_value}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method:

```py
from itertools import zip_longest

i = iter(example.items())

for col1, col2 in zip_longest(i, i):
    col1 = f"{col1[0]}: {col1[1]}"
    col2 = f"{col2[0]}: {col2[1]}" if col2 else ""
    print(f"{col1:<40} {col2:<40}")
```

Prints:

```
key0: val0                               key1: val1                              
key2: val2                               key3: val3                              
key4: val4                               key5: val5
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print formatted data to the console, maybe use the [rich library](https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tables.html#)?

```
from rich.console import Console
from rich.table import Table
from itertools import zip_longest

console = Console()
table = Table(show_header=False)

lst = iter(example.items())

for (k1, v1), (k2, v2) in zip_longest(lst, lst, fillvalue=("", "")):
    table.add_row(k1, v1, k2, v2)

console.print(table)
```

output (looks even better on an actual console...):

```
┏━━━━━━┳━━━━━━┳━━━━━━┳━━━━━━┓
┃ key0 ┃ val0 ┃ key1 ┃ val1 ┃
│ key2 │ val2 │ key3 │ val3 │
│ key4 │ val4 │ key5 │ val5 │
│ key6 │ val6 │      │      │
└──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┘
```